# JPA @ManyToOne update association link in both sides

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many

Class A

```
@ManyToOne 
private B b;
```

Class B

```
    @OneToMany (mappedBy ="b")
    private List<A> listA = new ArrayList<A>();
    private void addA(A a) {
    listA.add(a);
    }
```

So A is the owning side, 
If I do  A.setB(new B()) then I merge A everything will work and the association will be kept.

If I do B.addA(new A()) then I merge B, the link between A and B will not be updated right ?
What should I do so B.add(new A()) will update the link between A and B ?

Thank you very much

Comment: What if you @OneToMany(mappedBy="b", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) ?

Comment: have you tried refreshing A after merging B?

Comment: The state of the Entities in memory should reflect how the data should be saved. In this case, B should have a reference to A, and A should have B in it's list.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your question very well, but I think you should add in method addA

```
private void addA(A a) {
    listA.add(a);
    a.setB(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well it should be enought to set `cascade` attribute. If you want to "control" links through the B's collection set it to `@OneToMany(mappedBy="b", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)`.

[According to docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#cascade()), no operation are cascaded by default.